# How to stop bootstrap rows from overlapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web designing and bootstrap.

I want to show 4 columns and 3 rows but the rows are overlapping as you can see in the screenshot below

[image]

**I am using following code (Which I will be repeating 12 times to get 4 columns and 3 rows.**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 member" style="max-height:256px; min-height:256px;">
<div class="well"'.$boxShadowEffect.'>
    <div class="col-xs-12 nopad text-center">
        <a href="/'.$memberUrl.'">
        <div style="max-height: 212px; min-height: 212px;"> <img style="max-height: inherit; '.$imageShadowEffect.'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="'.$name.' is a '.$memberProfession.'" src="https://e27.co/img/no_image_profile.png">
        </div>
        </a>
        <a href="/'.$memberUrl.'">  <h4 class="tmargin bold text-info"  title="'.$nameTitle.'">'.$name.'</h4></a>
        <a class="tmargin btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" href="/'.$memberUrl.'">View '.$listingLabel.' </a>                                                  
    </div>                                              
    <div class="clearfix">  </div>                                                                                          
</div>
```

**Where should I be adding break tag?**

Comment: Don't set `max-height` on the columns: http://www.codeply.com/go/OH013YvjNc

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Came across this question where I had col nested in a column e.g. row > col > 
col and row > col. My solution was to rework the markup so each component has distinct structure e.g row > col

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set max-height on the columns:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 member" style="min-height:256px;">..</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/OH013YvjN